# Photoelectic effect

Tags: photoelectric-effect

Why does increasing potential across terminals increase the current in photoelectric effect?
Why dont all the electrons in the space charge get attracted to the anode when the potential difference is small?

Comment: Are you referring to measured data?

Comment: What potential are you talking about? Is this some experimental setup you're asking about, or is it Einstein's theory of the photoelectric effect? It's unclear what you are asking about.

Comment: @Bill N  "Potential across the terminals" should obviously mean the applied voltage to the terminals.

Comment: @freecharly "the terminals" of what?  If the OP is talking about how to operate an experimental device which demonstrates the photoelectric effect, OP should be specific. The point of my comment is that the photoelectric effect is not a device; it is a process in which there is no voltage or terminals.

Comment: @Bill N - You are, of course right! The wording of this question is very unsatisfactory.

Comment: What I’m trying to ask is why does corrent increase when voltage increases upto a point. Dont all electrons flow even if voltage is extremely low as they are attaracts by anode and repelled by cathode and neighbouring electrons

Comment: @VarunMaddipati In a standard photoelectric effect experimental tube, the purpose of the voltage is to **stop** the flow of photo-electrons. The difference in $h\nu$ and $V_{stop} is the work function. Without specific details of your experimental setup we can't determine what your question actually means.

Answer (score 1):

In a vacuum diode, the electrons are emitted from the metallic cathode by the impinging photons and produce an anode current when they reach the anode which increases with applied anode voltage until reaching a saturation current. This is due to the fact that at low applied anode voltages not all electrons can reach the anode because the electrons emitted from the cathode form a negatively charged electron cloud above the cathode surface which opposes the transport of emitted electrons to the anode. This is overcome by the increasing electric field produced at larger applied positive anode voltages so that all emitted electrons travel to the anode at high anode voltages. A similar effect, space charge limited emission (which is modeled by the [Child-Langmuir Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_charge#Child's_Law)), occurs in the vacuum diode with a hot cathode where thermionic electron emission is due to the high temperature of a heated filament.

Comment: Just a note: at low intensities, space-charge effects are not limiting the current.